# Help finding appropriate AVR device

Tags: microcontroller, avr, adc, uart

I am working on a student project and need to find AVR microcontroller that will suit all project requirements. Here's a simple list:

1. serial communication (UART),
2. at least two ADC channels,
3. PDIP package (for easy soldering, I do not have access to expensive equipment nor do I have skills to perform small-scale soldering),
4. four I/O ports (excluding UART connections).

I searched on Atmel's website and was stunned when I realised that no device exists that can support these simple requirements.

Here are two devices I considered:

- [ATtiny2313](http://www.atmel.com/devices/attiny2313.aspx) (does not have ADC)
- [ATtiny44](http://www.atmel.com/devices/attiny44.aspx) (does not support UART)

I hope that someone will be able to point me to the right device, as I failed to find one to match the requirements. Any recommendations will be much appreciated.

#### EDIT:

I've noticed that the device selection tool on Atmel's website is not much reliable, at least not in my case. If you list all 8-bit microcontrollers, remove all filters and filter by number of ADC channels (select at least one) and number of UARTs (select at least one), no device in a PDIP package (according to the selection in Packages filter) will be available. You can see the results [here](http://www.atmel.com/PFResults.aspx#%28data%3a%28area%3a%27%27,category%3a%2734864%5B33180%5B33083,33085,33086%5D%5D%27,mature%3a!f,pm%3a!%28%28i:8254,v%3a!%281,10%29%29,%28i:8462,v%3a!%281,8%29%29,%28i:9999,v%3a!n%29%29,view%3alist%29,sc:1%29).

Comment: The ATmega8 has everything you need. Farnell has over 2000 of them: http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/displayProduct.jsp?sku=1748534&action=view&CMP=GRHB-FINDCHIPS1-1000082

Comment: Atmel has a device selection tool on their website: www.atmel.com

Comment: I've noticed a lot of negative votes. Being a beginner in electronics, I relied on Atmel's website to search for the proper device. However, the device selection tool on their website is misleading. You can check it out for yourself - choose at least one ADC channel and one UART and clear all other criteria. When you select criteria by package, all PDIP packages will be grayed out. I should've used Digikey's selection tool, as it is more reliable.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević downvotes are only -2 rep while a single upvote is +5 on a question and +10 on an answer, this seems to lack research, but as has been discussed this is probably because you just had not yet learned how to efficiently research such a topic. Nothing to worry about, hope you have learned, in general looking for shopping advice is not a good fit. Please also mark an answer as an answer if it helped you solve your issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Digikey](http://www.Digikey.com) has excellent selection tools for its components. You can select on package, manufacturer, ADC, and other features. (Odd that memory size doen't seem to be important.)

I found 143 parts matching your requirements. The [ATmega48P](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8025.pdf) is 1.76 dollar in 1s and has 4 kB of Flash. The ATmega88P and ATmega168P are the same, but with 8 kB and 16 kB Flash, resp (same datasheet).

Comment: An alternative to Digikey is [Farnell](http://farnell.com/), who also have a very nice search system.

Comment: @Polynomial Aren't Farnell for companies only?

Comment: @exscape Nope, I order from them regularly. Just placed an order today, actually. You can always order from [CPC](http://cpc.farnell.com/) (if you're in the UK) which is Farnell's more consumer-friendly branch.

Comment: @exscape - No. But Farnell is expensive, the ATmega8 costs 29 % more than at Digikey. We use Farnell for its overnight delivery. If I urgently need a part to finish my prototype I can order it at 5 in the afternoon, and the next morning at 9 the parts are on my desk. But this has a price...

Comment: Huh. Have they changed that policy in the recent years? There are *tons* of posts on Swedish electronics forums about that very issue, including official Farnell info that they only trade with other companies.

Answer (score 0):

I think microcontroller AVR 32-p is appropriate for you , because it has many features which are able to use them for your student projects . It has 4 port I/O , PWM , ADC channels and etc.
I hope my answer will be helpful.

Comment: It probably would have been helpful if it had come about 15 months earlier and included a full part name.

Comment: "AVR-32" is a different architecture from "AVR" and may not practically meet the available-in-DIP requurement.

Comment: Avr microcontrollers Atmega series, 32-p it is available in DIP package with all the features which in needed.